# Lily Hbase Indexers exit for no reason

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am running a Cloudera/Solr cluster, and attempting to do NRT indexing of Hbase into Solr using the hbase-solr (Lily) indexer. The batch mode indexing works fine.

However, after I start loading data in a constant stream, the Lily indexers start dying one after the other. They don't print out an particular error messages that jump out at me, but all end the same way:

```
2014-09-10 16:04:56,770 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal,44013,1410329096767 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=ip-172-31-1-205.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181
2014-09-10 16:04:56,771 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.206:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-09-10 16:04:56,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=44013: starting
2014-09-10 16:04:56,771 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: starting
2014-09-10 16:04:56,773 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.206:2181, initiating session
2014-09-10 16:04:56,775 INFO com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.supervisor.IndexerSupervisor: Started indexer for indexFeature
2014-09-10 16:04:56,776 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.206:2181, sessionid = 0x1485c7ff13602fd, negotiated timeout = 60000
2014-09-10 16:04:56,813 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:04:57,287 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Done importing commands
2014-09-10 16:04:57,289 INFO org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil: Creating new http client, config:
2014-09-10 16:04:57,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcServer: regionserver/ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.204:0: started 10 reader(s).
2014-09-10 16:04:57,299 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=ip-172-31-1-205.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal,44713,1410329097297, quorum=ip-172-31-1-205.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2014-09-10 16:04:57,301 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal,44713,1410329097297 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=ip-172-31-1-205.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-206.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:2181
2014-09-10 16:04:57,302 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.204:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-09-10 16:04:57,303 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: starting
2014-09-10 16:04:57,303 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.204:2181, initiating session
2014-09-10 16:04:57,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=44713: starting
2014-09-10 16:04:57,306 INFO com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.supervisor.IndexerSupervisor: Started indexer for indexSeenBlock
2014-09-10 16:04:57,307 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server ip-172-31-1-204.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.204:2181, sessionid = 0x3485c7fee8f0374, negotiated timeout = 60000
2014-09-10 16:04:57,349 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2014-09-10 16:04:57,536 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2
2014-09-10 16:04:58,663 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:11060
2014-09-10 16:05:01,591 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,597 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,641 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,650 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,688 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,726 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,732 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,740 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
2014-09-10 16:05:01,752 INFO org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineContext: Importing commands
```

The Cloudera manager doesn't give any useful information either, besides saying the processes have exited. Some records do get updated in the Solr index, indicating the indexers are working correctly for at least a little while.

I am running the latest CDH 5.1 on RHEL6.5 and JDK7.

Comment: Hi were you able to fix this ? what was the fix? In my case, my comments below helped me since I switched off the WAL. when I switched on then it  started working. wanted to know what are the other cases. pls reply

Comment: @RamPrasadG I recommend not using Hbase and especially not Lily. If you are putting data into Solr, try using the direct Solr JSON API. If you want a better database than HBase, try Kudu (beta).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAL i.e. Write a head log option is FALSE in your hbase client program like mapreduce(for performance reasons). it wont write in to HLOG.

NRT works on WAL/HLOG.

Batch Index works fine since it doesn't work on WAL